# Fastest way to read a file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, file-access

My application currently implements a FileSystemWatcher object to monitor a directory (C:\Incoming) for the creation of a file (Input.xml).

I'm currently using a Streamreader object to read the file into my application, however I'm concerned about performance considering that the data will be used to perform operations in a SQL Server database.

What would be the FASTEST way to read the file into memory (or am I already using it)?

Comment: What are the size ranges of the files? What exact code are you using to read those files?

Comment: You're interacting with the slowest part of the system (physical disk).  There is really no reason to geek on performance.  If you *needed* it faster, you could consider using a RAM disk or SSD for your input folder.

Comment: What role is SQL-Server playing? _"however I'm concerned about performance considering that the data will be used to perform operations in a SQL Server database. "_ Note that you can **bulk import** into sql-server directly from  files. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: The question is how do you process that xml?  Are you just reading nodes at a time to generate individual sql statements or do you have to process the entire file before you can generate any SQL.  If it is the prior then I would use LINQ XML and process the SQL statements asynch.  Often you can parse faster than SQL can insert.

Comment: Reading the file is going to be the least of your worries. If you just want to get the data into memory, you'll be hard pressed to improve on `File.ReadAllBytes`. But I suspect your real question is somewhat more involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the standard approach to the task.

If you need to load the data (large data, that is) into a database, the bottleneck will be between your code and the database, unless you use a `BULK INSERT` technique, as opposed to inserting rows one by one.  The details of that depend on the particular database server.
This is however no concern if the files are relatively small in which case the load will be more evenly distributed.  Even then I would not care much about the speed of disk access.

Make sure that the file is completely written before you start reading it.  For example, try opening it for exclusive reading first.  It does help a bit if the file is make accessible to you through a rename operation as opposed to a create operation, especially if you expect many files to be arriving, because your server side then does not have to busy wait until the file is completely written.  This basically means that the file should first be written with a file name for which you are NOT watching.

Answer (score 0):

.NET has the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class too